# How to access extra properties defined in build.gradle in a Groovy class?

Tags: gradle, groovy, properties

I am defining an extra property in build.gradle:

```
ext {
 GRGIT_TARGET_REPO = ...
}
```

I have a groovy class under buildSrc/src/main/groovy

```
class Utils {
   def test() {
      println GRGIT_TARGET_REPO
   }
}
```

I have another gradle file which can access GRGIT_TARGET_REPO just fine. But if it calls the function in the class:

```
Utils utils = new Utils()
utils.test()
```

On calling the above function, I get the following error:

`No such property: GRGIT_TARGET_REPO for class: Utils`

Is there a way to access project/extra properties in Groovy classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to send the gradle `project` object into your Utils class to accomplish what you want. In other words:

```
class Utils {
   def project

   def test() {
      println(project.ext.GRGIT_TARGET_REPO)
   }
}
```

and

```
def utils = new Utils(project: project)
utils.test()
```

in your build.gradle file.

Every gradle build file has a [`project` instance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) as its delegate which means that you can call all methods in the [project class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) directly from the build file code. The example here is that the above `project` access calls the [getProject](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getProject--) method on the project object.

For extra properties, there is an "extra properties" section in the above groovy/javadoc for the Project object.